# Detect pattern of motion on an Android device

Tags: android, mobile, android-sensors, motion

I want to detect a specific pattern of motion on an Android mobile phone, e.g. if I do five sit-stands.

[Note: I am currently detecting the motion but the motion in all direction is the same.]

What I need is:

1. I need to differentiate the motion downward, upward, forward and backward.
2. I need to find the height of the mobile phone from ground level (and the height of the person holding it).

Is there any sample project which has pattern motion detection implemented?

Answer (score 7):

This isn't impossible, but it may not be extremely accurate, given that the accuracy of the accelerometer and gyroscopes in phones have improved a lot.

What your app will doing is taking sensor data, and doing a [regression analysis.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_analysis)

1) You will need to build a model of data that you classify as five sit and stands. This could be done by asking the user to do five sit and stands, or by loading the app with a more fine-tuned model from data that you've collected beforehand. There may be tricks you could do, such as loading several models of people with different heights, and asking the user to submit their own height in the app, to use the best model.

2) When run, your app will be trying to fit the [data from the sensors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_set) (Android has [great libraries for this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html)), to the model that you've made. Hopefully, when the user performs five sit-stands, he will generate a set of motion data similar enough to your definition of five sit-stands that your algorithm accepts it as such.

A lot of the work here is assembling and classifying your model, and playing with it until you get an acceptable accuracy. Focus on what makes a stand-sit unique to other up and down motions - For instance, there might be a telltale sign of extending the legs in the data, followed by a different shape for straightening up fully. Or, if you expect the phone to be in the pocket, you may not have a lot of rotational motion, so you can reject test sets that registered lots of change from the gyroscope.

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible. You can recognize downward and upward comparing acceleration with main gravity force but how do you know is your phone is in the back pocket when you rise or just in your waving hand when you say hello? Was if 5 stand ups or 5 hellos?
Forward and backward are even more unpredictable. What is forward for upside-down phone? What if forward at all from phone point of view?
And ground level as well as height are completely out of measurement. Phone will move and produce accelerations in exact way for dwarf or giant - it more depends on person behavior or motionless then on height.

Comment: I disagree. It's not perfect - but that's true for many fields of CS. Given the accuracy of sensors nowadays, it's not unreasonable to build models to guess what a wearer is doing. For example, the emerging field/industry of Wireless Health focuses on issues like this. I worked once with a professor who used sensors - not unlike the ones in OPs phone - on stroke victims, that could help diagnose potential problems from walking gait. In OP's case, sure, you will get false positives, but it would not be hard to tell between a wave and a stand-up by looking at sensor data.

Answer (score 2):

It's a topic of research and probably I'm way too late to post it here, but I'm foraging the literature anyway, so what?

All kind of machine learning approaches have been set on the issue, I'll mention some on the way. Andy Ng's [MOOC on machine learning](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning) gives you an entry point to the field and into Matlab/Octave that you instantly can put to practice, it demystifies the monsters too ("Support vector machine").

I'd like to detect if somebody is drunk from phone acceleration and maybe angle, therefore I'm flirting with neuronal networks for the issue (they're good for [every issue](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiaoo6xvbXLAhVqP5oKHYK9CD4QFgghMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.cs.toronto.edu%2F~vmnih%2Fdocs%2Fdqn.pdf&usg=AFQjCNEd1AJoM72DeDpI_GBoPuv7NnVoFA&sig2=rIQFBSMPGuvY4aGyqvMDfw) basically, if you can afford the hardware), since I don't want to assume pre-defined patterns to look for.

Your task could be approached pattern based it seems, an approach applied to classify [golf play motions](http://www.ipcbee.com/vol56/008-ICCEB2013-IC500.pdf), [dancing](http://smcnetwork.org/files/proceedings/2010/28.pdf), behavioural [every day walking patterns](http://www.math.unipd.it/~cpalazzi/papers/Palazzi-Accelerometer.pdf), and two times [drunk driving detection](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwirl46FxLXLAhXpHJoKHfpzDK4QFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ijraset.com%2Ffileserve.php%3FFID%3D2926&usg=AFQjCNGjwaZEYXbaS--cYLGqjV28g1gjhA&sig2=hUVZJDzGdF3kCsoB4FmWRg) where [one](http://web.cse.ohio-state.edu/~xuan/papers/10_perhealth_dtbsx.pdf) addresses the issue of finding a base line for what actually is longitudinal motion as opposed to every other direction, which maybe could contribute to find the baselines you need, like what is the ground level.

It is a dense shrub of aspects and approaches, below just some more.

- Lim e.a. 2009: [Real-time End Point Detection Specialized for Acceleration Signal](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/224080754)
- He & Yin 2009: [Activity Recognition from acceleration data Based on
  Discrete Consine Transform and SVM](http://www.hcii-lab.net/download/papers/conference/Activity%20Recognition%20from%20acceleration%20data%20Based%20on%20Discrete%20Consine%20Transform%20and%20SVM.pdf)
- Dhoble e.a. 2012: [Online Spatio-Temporal Pattern Recognition with Evolving Spiking Neural Networks utilising Address Event Representation, Rank Order, and Temporal Spike Learning](http://ncs.ethz.ch/pubs/pdf/Dhoble_etal12.pdf)
- Panagiotakis e.a.: [Temporal segmentation and seamless stitching of motion patterns for synthesizing novel animations of periodic dances](http://hobbit.acin.tuwien.ac.at/publications/2014_08_ICPR_danceanimation.pdf)

This one uses visual data, but walks you through a matlab implementation of a neuronal network classifier:

- Symeonidis 2000: [Hand Gesture Recognition Using Neural Networks](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj5mobczbXLAhWiApoKHarPC3wQFgghMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ee.surrey.ac.uk%2FPersonal%2FT.Windeatt%2Fmsc_projects%2Fsymeonidis%2FFinal%2520Project.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFAgezIxdW5z7xV3bpYMT2NOztFWQ&sig2=q7PshiAUvAQhhChh5VawZg)

Answer (score 1):

I do not necessarily agree with Alex's response. This is possible (although maybe not as accurate as you would like) using accelerometer, device rotation and ALOT of trial/error and data mining.

The way I see that this can work is by defining a specific way that the user holds the device (or the device is locked and positioned on the users' body). As they go through the motions the orientation combined with acceleration and time will determine what sort of motion is being performed. You will need to use class objects like OrientationEventListener, SensorEventListener, SensorManager, Sensor and various timers e.g. Runnables or TimerTasks.

From there, you need to gather a lot of data. Observe, record and study what the numbers are for doing specific actions, and then come up with a range of values that define each movement and sub-movements. What I mean by sub-movements is, maybe a situp has five parts:

1) Rest position where phone orientation is x-value at time x

2) Situp started where phone orientation is range of y-values at time y (greater than x)

3) Situp is at final position where phone orientation is range of z-values at time z (greater than y)

4) Situp is in rebound (the user is falling back down to the floor) where phone orientation is range of y-values at time v (greater than z)

5) Situp is back at rest position where phone orientation is x-value at time n (greatest and final time)

Add acceleration to this as well, because there are certain circumstances where acceleration can be assumed. For example, my hypothesis is that people perform the actual situp (steps 1-3 in my above breakdown) at a faster acceleration than when they are falling back. In general, most people fall slower because they cannot see what's behind them. That can also be used as an additional condition to determine the direction of the user. This is probably not true for all cases, however, which is why your data mining is necessary. Because I can also hypothesize that if someone has done many situps, that final situp is very slow and then they just collapse back down to rest position due to exhaustion. In this case the acceleration will be opposite of my initial hypothesis.

Lastly, check out Motion Sensors: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html

All in all, it is really a numbers game combined with your own "guestimation". But you might be surprised at how well it works. Perhaps (hopefully) good enough for your purposes.

Good luck!